# AOSP. How to create jar(system/framework)

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I wanna modify service.jar. I downloaded aosp project. As I understand I should create build based on root/frameworks/base/services folder. How I can do this? I thought that I should use make -f for Adroid.mk, bt got "make: *** No targets.  Stop.". How I should modify file for create .jar?

it will be nice if somebody share link to books(store)/guides/etc for AOSP

Comment: do you mean how to build a specific module ?

Comment: @MushahidGillani yeah. how build only 1 module

Comment: go to services directory and execute mma command

Comment: just type mma .